# Is there a "changelog" of major new features of Git?

Tags: git

I'm looking for Git's equivalent of Mercurial's [What's New](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WhatsNew) page or Eclipse's [New and Noteworthy](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2010/09/06/eclipse-4-1-and-3-7-indigo-new-and-noteworthy). So far I have only been able to find a raw changelog but a higher-level document describing only the major new features would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always have a look at the [ReleaseNotes](https://github.com/gitster/git/tree/master/Documentation/RelNotes) for each version